# Python Image Library(PIL) saving gif, TypeError: int() argument must be a string

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am saving random images from a crawler but sometimes I am getting this error when I save the image,

```
PIL/GifImagePlugin.py, line 487, in _write_local_header
transparency = int(transparency)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a 
number, not 'tuple'
```

If an extension is "gif" then I am saving the image

```
img.save(path, save_all=True)
```

I tried google but there were no solutions for this.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is the variable transparency?

Comment: Can not reproduce. You should provide more information about what you're doing to load or create that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an open Pillow issue for this bug https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2803